# TypeError: cannot read property of undefined (ExpressJS/POST)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, post, body-parser

I have looked at all similar questions and none are working for me. I have a node js app in which I cannot print the input text from a form, using body-parser.

My index.ejs:

```
         <form id="demo-2" method = "POST" action="/search">
<input type="search" name = "searcher" placeholder="Search">
                    </form>
```

Index.js:

```
var cool = require('cool-ascii-faces');
var express = require('express');

var app = express();
var pg = require('pg');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var env = require('node-env-file');

app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 5000));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/views/'));

// views is directory for all template files
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

//app.use(express.bodyParser());


//DIFFERENT APPS - tells them what to do

app.post('/search', function(request, response) {
    //var username = req.body;

    console.log("posted something"+ request.body.searcher);
    response.end("something was posted: "+ request.body.searcher);
});

app.get('/search', function(request, response) {
     response.send("skylarr");

});
```

And despite using the input's name searcher I get error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'searcher' of undefined`

What is wrong here?

Comment: you comment out body-parser middle ware. why? un comment that and then try.

Comment: That created an error regarding middleware and wouldn't let the app run.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`body-parser` is not the part of express. Install it separately using `npm install body-parser --save`  and then use it as middleware. check the code after line where you commented `express.bodyParser()` middleware

```
var cool = require('cool-ascii-faces');
var express = require('express');

var app = express();
var pg = require('pg');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var env = require('node-env-file');

app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 5000));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/views/'));

// views is directory for all template files
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

//app.use(express.bodyParser());

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));


//DIFFERENT APPS - tells them what to do

app.post('/search', function(request, response) {
    //var username = req.body;

    console.log("posted something"+ request.body.searcher);
    response.end("something was posted: "+ request.body.searcher);
});

app.get('/search', function(request, response) {
     response.send("skylarr");

});
```

Comment: @skyguy you told in above comment if you un comment `bodyParser` that create an error regarding middle ware. I want to tell that `bodyParser` is not the part of express. install and use it separately.

Comment: Doesn't work for me, still displaying the exact same error

Answer (score 4):

You are missing the body parser. You need to tell express to use the body parser as a middleware.

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

Add these two lines above the app.post().

Answer (score 1):

There is no `body` property on a standard Node.JS HTTP request.  That key is patched on by the `bodyParser` middleware.

You can either add the `bodyParser` middleware, or (if you don't want to parse the body for some reason) use query or URL parameters to pass `searcher`.

Comment: Sorry I'm new to this. Can you give an example of those 2 options?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of bodyparser you could use `app.use(express.json())`.